# scalap detection of value classes

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I'm using scalap to pick apart information about Scala classes.  Works fine for case classes, but I want to see if a class is a value class.  So far I haven't found anything that will tell me that.  Anyone know of a way to differentiate a value class from a non-value class?

Comment: By the way: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scala-internals/wAR-E9HQLmA (no, it is not scalap solution, but might help somebody who will find this thread).

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat ValueClass.scala
class ValueClass(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def rcap = s.reverse.toUpperCase
}

$ scalap -cp . ValueClass
final class ValueClass extends scala.AnyVal {
  val s : scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
  def this(s : scala.Predef.String) = { /* compiled code */ }
  def rcap : java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
  override def hashCode() : scala.Int = { /* compiled code */ }
  override def equals(x$1 : scala.Any) : scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }
}
object ValueClass extends scala.AnyRef {
  def this() = { /* compiled code */ }
  final def rcap$extension($this : ValueClass) : java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
  final def hashCode$extension($this : ValueClass)() : scala.Int = { /* compiled code */ }
  final def equals$extension($this : ValueClass)(x$1 : scala.Any) : scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

The first line gives it away, no?: final class ValueClass extends **scala.AnyVal**

Edit: if you're not using scalap and you want to do it at runtime, you can (very hackishly)

```
class V(val v: Int) extends AnyVal {}
reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[V].typeSymbol.companionSymbol.
  typeSignature.members.exists(_.name.toString.endsWith("$extension"))
```

at least for now.  Maybe in the future there will be an easier-to-grab `isValueClass` flag.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm having trouble with it in practice.  If I get a Class object for my class I can call clazz.getSuperclass I get Object, not AnyVal.  I also tried clazz.isInstanceOf[AnyVal] and the compiler wasn't having it.  So I'm having trouble figuring out how to test for AnyVal parentage.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's not exactly "using scalap", is it?